# In yii How to generate login functionality

Tags: extjs, yii

In yii i am creating login functionalities. But in my case client side design is in extjs and server side design is in Yii framework. So in yii controller i want to create login functionality in such a way that client will enter username and password. In extjs this data will be accepted in Json format,it is then encoded and sent to server. So now at server side  i will receive username and password. so my work is to create login functionality in Yii using this received username and password from extjs. i.e. at starting phase i want to create login functionality assuming hard coded username and password. So can you please help me.

Comment: In yii i am having actionLogin method as public function actionLogin(){$model=new LoginForm;
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
{ $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
 // validate user input 
       if ($model->validate()) 
       {if($model->login()) {$command->insert('trans', array('id'=>Yii::app()->user->getId(),
)); $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
} }$this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));} But in this,it is taking values from form in yii.I want to create method using username and password sent by extjs.So how can i modify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using POST method inf from to send JSON encrypted data in the login form, you can retrieve it in controller with $_POST['your_post_variable'] similar to actionLogin method (Note: Make sure that you are calling correct method in form action).

Please share the Login Form.

Regards,
HBK